# HTML: Mac-like and Windows-like file browser UI

Tags: html, windows-explorer, finder, file-manager

What are the most accurate HTML/JS browser-based "clones" of the OSX Finder file-browsing UI and the Windows Explorer file-browsing UI?

1. I'm not necessarily looking for any back-end functionality for actually moving/renaming/etc files and folders -- it could just be UI code that alters an in-memory JS object for example.  Then I would write the code to actually modify files on a remote host.
2. I'm not interested in any 'advanced' features of OSX Finder or Windows Explorer like connecting to network hosts or burning discs -- just the basics: copy, paste, move, rename files+folders, create folders, sort entries by filetype/name/modification-date, etc.

Comment: I think trying to clone an OS file manager on the web is going to run into "uncanny valley"-type issues. There's only so far you can go before it is really obvious that it isn't the real thing, and the similarity will only make the missing bits even more glaring. Plus, to cover Windows, you'd need 3 different themes (XP, Vista, Win7 - 4 once Win8 comes out), and you'll still never be able to account for people that use customized colors or other custom theme-y stuff. (cont)

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment to your question, not an answer.

Comment: Have a look on smashingmagazine.com for icon sets resembling what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good html/css example here: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/mac-osx-lion-css3

and a few older examples here: http://www.therestartpage.com